# Invert a test in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to prevent TODO comments (or other problematic strings) from being checked in with a gitlab CI test rule. I added the last line here:

```
.job_template: &template_test
  image: python:3.6-stretch
  tags:
    - python
  # ...

stages:
  - test

test:
  <<: *template_test
  stage: test
  script:
    - flake8 *.py
    - ! grep TODO *.py
```

But when I look at the output of the runner, it fails:

```
$ flake8 *.py
$ grep TODO *.py
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It seems like Gitlab swallowed the exclamation mark `!`, used in the shell to [negate the return value of grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367069/35070).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!` is a [reserved character in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664113/what-does-a-single-exclamation-mark-do-in-yaml), therefore this does not work.

However, in this case you could use a `if..then` expression:

```
- if [ "$(grep TODO *.py)" != "" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

Answer (score 19):

A line with the exclamation mark (`! grep ...`) at the beginning must be quoted. However, even this (`'! grep ...'`) will not work here, return code will always be zero. I got the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549913/491884, a subshell must be started because GitLab CI starts the shell with `set -e`. This should work and is reasonably short:

```
script:
...
- (! grep TODO *.py)
```